# Resta de fechas en Oracle

Tags: oracle-11g

El día de hoy trabajando con fechas en Oracle, realice una resta de fecha con la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT TO_DATE(SYSDATE, 'DD/MM/YYYY') AS HOY, 
      TO_DATE(T.FECHA, 'DD/MM/YYYY') AS FECHA, 
      TO_DATE(SYSDATE, 'DD/MM/YYYY') - TO_DATE(T.FECHA, 'DD/MM/YYYY') AS RESTA 
FROM tabla t
WHERE T.FECHA IS NOT NULL
```

La cual me arrojo los siguientes resultados:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como ven la resta me arroja resultados negativos, claro que no son los esperados, haciendo pruebas realizo la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT TO_DATE(SYSDATE, 'DD/MM/YYYY') AS HOY, 
      TO_DATE(T.FECHA, 'DD/MM/YYYY') AS FECHA, 
      TO_DATE(SYSDATE) - TO_DATE(T.FECHA, 'DD/MM/YYYY') AS RESTA 
FROM tabla t
WHERE T.FECHA IS NOT NULL
```

La cual me arrojo los siguientes resultados:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estos si son los resultados esperados. Aquí mi duda cual es la diferencia entre realizar la resta de la siguiente manera `TO_DATE(SYSDATE, 'DD/MM/YYYY') - TO_DATE(T.FECHA, 'DD/MM/YYYY')` a la manera en que me arrojo los resultados correctos `TO_DATE(SYSDATE) - TO_DATE(T.FECHAEVAL, 'DD/MM/YYYY')`?

Como nota el campo `T.FECHA` es `VARCHAR2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Aplicar `TO_CHAR` a `SYSDATE` (que es una función que devuelve el valor de tipo de datos `DATE`) con la máscara de formato adecuada para mostrarlo como *dd/mm/aaaa*.
- Seleccione `FECHA` tal como está, ya que lo ha almacenado como *dd/mm/aaaa*, por lo tanto, no sirve para convertirlo a la fecha (con `TO_DATE`)
- Como restar dos valores de fecha produce el número de días entre esos dos valores, apliqué la función `TRUNC` a `SYSDATE` para eliminar el componente de tiempo de ella, y `TO_DATE` a `FECHA` para convertirla a la fecha.

  ```
  select to_char(sysdate, 'dd/mm/yyyy') as hoy, 
         fecha as fecha,
         trunc(sysdate) - to_date(fecha, 'dd/mm/yyyy') as resta 
    from table;
  ```

El resultado:

```
Hoy         Fecha       Resta
03/08/2018  13/05/2009  3369
03/08/2018  14/05/2009  3368
03/08/2018  08/05/2009  3374
03/08/2018  23/07/2010  2933
03/08/2018  22/09/2010  2872
03/08/2018  08/05/2009  3374
03/08/2018  28/04/2009  3384
```