# Obtener dia anterior en una consulta SQL en Oracle

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, oracle

Necesito obtener el registro anterior mediante una fecha, he intentado con:

```
SELECT G305.G305S01 FROM BI_SRC.GSCF305 G305, BI_SRC.GSCF300 G300 WHERE TRUNC(G305.G305FDIA) = '2019/02/15' - 1 AND G300.G300UUID = G305.G301UUID AND G300.G300CTA = '1944032562'
```

Pero me sale el siguiente error:

> ORA-00932: tipos de dato inconsistentes: se esperaba DATE se ha obtenido NUMBER

Tambien he intentado usar `LEAD` pero me trae datos vacios:

```
SELECT LEAD(G305.G305S01, 1) OVER(ORDER BY G305.G305S01)  FROM BI_SRC.GSCF305 G305, BI_SRC.GSCF300 G300 WHERE TRUNC(G305.G305FDIA) = '2019/02/15' AND G300.G300UUID = G305.G301UUID AND G300.G300CTA = '1944032562';
```

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: No estoy seguro de si funciona en oracle pero podrías usar por ejemplo `WHERE DAY(campo_fecha) = dia_que_necesitas` esto mismo es aplicable con `YEAR`o `MONTH`

Comment: Puedes revisar [este enlace](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/149637/resta-de-fechas-en-oracle), a ver si te sirve.

Comment: O [este otro enlace](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/65571/como-puedo-restar-dos-fechas-y-que-me-devuelva-horas-minutos-y-segundos-oracle). Ambos son de aquí, ojalá te ayuden.

Comment: debes hacer un `TO_DATE('2019/02/15', 'yyyy/mm/dd'))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para poder obtener el registro anterior mediante una fecha, hice un:

```
TO_DATE('2019/02/15', 'yyyy/mm/dd')-1
```

en el campo fecha. Es decir:

```
SELECT G305.G305S01 FROM BI_SRC.GSCF305 G305 WHERE TRUNC(G305.G305FDIA) = TO_DATE('2019/02/15', 'YYYY/MM/DD')-1 AND G300.G300UUID = G305.G301UUID
```